# How to password protect grub boot menu in Fedora 38?

Tags: fedora, grub2

I have been trying to password-protect grub boot menu in Fedora 38. Now, unfortunately, the [Fedora guide for GRUB2](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/installing-grub2/) is "currently in the process of revision," so I have had to work with other guides such as [this one](https://www.tecmint.com/password-protect-grub-in-linux/) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457821/how-do-you-change-the-grub2-username-password).

What I have done is, according to the instructions in the sources above,

1. call `grub2-set-password` to set up a password.
2. call `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` to recreate grub configuration.

This has had no effect on grub boot menu: I can still edit kernel parameters with 'e.' I *can* see that the password has been stored into `/boot/grub2/user.cfg` and I *can* see that `/etc/grub.d/01_users` should then set `superuser` and other values appropriately, as indicated in the answer link above.

So: *how can I achieve what I am trying to do?*

Edit. `grub2-set-password` stores the password into file `/boot/grub2/user.cfg`, while in an UEFI system the script `01_users` tries to read the password from file `${prefix}/user.cfg`. Given that in an UEFI system other boot information is contained in directory `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora`, perhaps `grub2-set-password` stores the password into an incorrect directory in this case. I wonder what `${prefix}` is in UEFI.

Comment: one shouldn't use `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` since Fedora 34! See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/grub2-bootloader/#_installing_grub2_on_a_uefi_system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `grub2-set-password` in UEFI boot systems. `grub2-set-password` stores the resulting password in `/boot/grub2/user.cfg`, which would be the correct location for legacy BIOS boot. UEFI boot tries to read this information from `${prefix}/user.cfg`, which - based on an experiment - seems to map to `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/user.cfg`.

As a temporary solution, the following solves the problem in an UEFI boot system (this is the experiment referred to above),

1. call `grub2-set-password` to generate the password
2. `mv /boot/grub2/user.cfg /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/`

Calling `grub2-mkconfig` after this does not seem to be necessary: all the code for reading the password is already in `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` even before the password is generated and stored.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually one sholdn't use `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` anymore (since Fedora 34)! See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/grub2-bootloader/#_installing_grub2_on_a_uefi_system

Answer (score 0):

This method comes from the article
[How to Add Password Protect to Grub Boot Menu in Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Debian](https://fostips.com/password-protect-grub-bootmenu-linux/)
where you may find much more details and with screenshots.

Here is a summary of the article for Fedora.

**Generate a hashed password**

Run in Terminal the command `grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` and
copy the output string starts with `grub.pbkdf2.sha512…`.

**Add Password Protect to Grub boot-menu**

- Edit the configuration file by running in terminal:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
  ```
- Add two new lines (password in plain text):

  ```
  set superusers="USER_NAME"
  password USER_NAME PASSWORD
  ```

  Or generate instead a hash for the password:

  ```
  set superusers="USER_NAME"
  password_pbkdf2 USER_NAME encryption_key
  ```
- Press Ctrl+X, type `y` and hit Enter to save the file.

**Apply changes**

Run the following command in terminal.

For UEFI boot:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

For legacy BIOS boot:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Good point on making the correct `mkconfig`call for UEFI, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem. On Fedora 38, password generation and setting the correct environment variables is automated by `grub2-set-password` and the file `01_users`, which do what you have done manually here.

Comment: However, pointing to UEFI might have provided a valuable piece of information: perhaps `grub2-set-password` saves password info into incorrect directory. See edit in origiinal question.