# How to override grub_arg in grubby for non-default grub entries in Fedora 38?

Tags: fedora, grub2

After [discovering and working around a bug](https://superuser.com/questions/1801209/how-to-password-protect-grub-boot-menu-in-fedora-38) in `grub2-set-password`, I am now able to set password protection for grub2 in Fedora 38. While this method asks for a password when trying to edit a grub menu entry with 'e', it does *not* stop a regular user from booting non-default grub entries.

[Grub 2.06 documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Authentication-and-authorisation) states that

> Superusers are permitted to use the GRUB command line, edit menu entries, and execute any menu entry.

The problem is the last action: stopping the execution of non-default menu entries without password. In Fedora 38, after password-protecting grub, a superusers group is indeed created, but I can still execute non-default menu entries without password.

I can see that password protection for grub menu entries is effectively disabled by each individual file in `/boot/loader/entries/`. Every file sets `grub-arg --unrestricted`, which according to [Grub 2.06 documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Authentication-and-authorisation) means that there is no restriction as to who can boot that entry. I also found [a discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686369/does-gnu-grub-support-bls-boot-loader-specification) indicating that Fedora patches grub to combine it with Boot Loader Specification (BLS). This suggests that the issue could be very much Fedora-specific. More information on this feature in Fedora can be found in [the Fedora change description on BLS](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/BootLoaderSpecByDefault).

I can also see that `grub_arg --unrestricted` has been hard coded into the new version of `grubby`, which is just a bash script in F38.

So the question is: *For non-default grub entries, how does one correctly override `grub_arg --unrestricted`, which is hard-coded into `grubby`?*